# choco meteor install - customize / different installation location

Tags: meteor, npm, choco

Hi I am trying to install meteor with choco using

```
choco install meteor
```

And I understand it will install in `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\.meteor\`.

Is there a way to install directly to different folder. Or once installed is it good to move to different folder  ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for now meteor isn't giving an option to install on a different location. In these two issue ([a](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2268), [b](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8489)) you can read more.

This is the bottom line from [abernix](https://github.com/abernix):

> As to your request, while using a global install shared by multiple users might seem nice in some aspects, it would cause permissions issues for many users who might not be able to install things outside their home directory. Meteor has no global configuration which would allow the location of the .meteor directory to be set, but you are welcome to move the Meteor installation wherever you would like, but currently, the .meteor directory does need to be in the home directory, and we currently have no intentions to re-work that, mainly as we start make considerations for a full transition to npm, which would solve this.

If you find something else I would like to know as well.